# Where can I find Nunit GUI RUNNER for 3.01 and how to run it?

Tags: nunit-3.0

How to run nunit 3 GUI Runner?

After installing `NUnit.3.0.1.msi` --> I don't see the GUI Runner under

> C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org

Where can I find it and how to start `GUI`?

Answer (score 3):

The GUI runner for NUnit 3 is still [under development](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-gui), version 0.1 is expected to be ready soon.

In the mean time, you can run either with the nunit console. (Or alternatively, within Visual Studio with the [NUnit 3 VS Adapter](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter), with you can install as a Visual Studio extension.)